# Finding directory path of laravel project installed on android phone

Tags: android, laravel

I have installed Laravel on my Android mobile phone using Termux. The problem is that I do not know where it is installed and therefore I can't put the project files into a text editor on the mobile phone. Also, I can't find the project folder when I connect the mobile to my laptop and use search(through hidden files as well). I have tried to go up in folder structure using $cd .. in terminux, up to a point where the permission was restricted, so I didn't figured out where those folders would possibly be. Any suggestion would be appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found the answer. You need to change the current folder in which Termux is installed(data/data/com.termux/files/) to a folder where you can access your files with a file explorer(in my case I used sdcard) like so:

```
$cd /sdcard
```

Then, if u run Android 6 or higher, you need to allow termux to create new directories using the command:

```
$termux-setup-storage
```

After that you are able to create a new directory in sdcard with

```
$mkdir YourDirectory
```

and you are able to access it. Good luck!